# Interactive Putty after remote commands & remotely sudo login

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, automation, putty

I'm trying to run commands in putty remotely & unfortunately i stuck on two problems.

> Putty cli closed after running those commands.

> I want sudo login remotely without prompt for password

***Note**: I already found solution for both problems & posting this question for future use.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem solution detail in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/587629/how-to-run-a-remote-command-in-putty-after-login-keep-the-shell-running/1575449#1575449)

Second problem solved by first two line of **RemoteCommands.txt** first line suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-being-prompted-for-a-password-by-sudo/470387#answer-634209) & after running that i run `sudo -i` to do sudo login but it didn't prompt for password. so it solve accidentally.

> **VBScript.vbs**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Exec("C:\Putty\putty.exe -ssh <username>@<ip> -pw <password> -P <port> -m ""E:\putty\RemoteCommands.txt"" -t")
```

> **RemoteCommands.txt**

```
sudo -S <<< "<password>" ls
sudo -i
/bin/bash
```

> **BatchFile.bat** *to run vbscript easily*

```
@echo off
start cmd /k "cd /d E:\putty & cscript VBScript.vbs & exit"
```

**Edited**

> To run commands after sudo login you can write something like this

`sudo -i -- bash -c 'cmd1; cmd2'` or `sudo -i -- bash -c 'cmd1 && cmd2'`

I found this workaround from this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-sudo-under-linux-or-unix/) & with random tries. so i got no explanation about this :D ... if any one know detail about this please edit this answere & provide links

> **RemoteCommands.txt**

```
sudo -S <<< "<password>" ls
sudo -i -- bash -c 'cd /home/shajji && npm start && /bin/bash'
/bin/bash
```